# IOS8: AVFoundation Camera Freeze

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8, avfoundation

Possible Duplicate: [Custom Camera View Not Working on iOS 8/Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986600/custom-camera-view-not-working-on-ios-8-xcode-6)

I'm using `AVFoundation` to capture still images. It was working fine until `iOS8` arrival. On `IOS8` if my app goes to background while camera layer is still floating and then after app comes in foreground the camera layer freezes and calling capture image method does't work. Any help?

Comment: have you tried to stop capturing the camera when your app goes to the background? and have you tried to start capturing camera directly when your app goes foreground again?

Comment: yes, i did. i started doing it on viewwillappear & viewWillDisappear but it still freezes.

Comment: the `–viewWillAppear:` or `–viewWillDisappear:` is not the proper place to catch the changes of the application's life cycle. you need to observe the proper notifications about the state-changes instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this...

In –viewWillAppear:   start camera capture on main thread, like this..

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if (![session isRunning])
        {              
                [session startRunning];
        }
});
```